# Understanding 買ってみたのに対応機種が違う

Tags: grammar

I am uncertain about how to interpret 買ってみたのに対応機種が違う below:

> そんなDOS時代の美少女ゲームはユーザーにもいろいろ大変なことがあった。そのひとつが、同一ソフトなのにパソコンの機種ごとにバージョンがあったこと。今のユーザーには理解できないかもしれないが、当時はゲームをレジに持っていくと「PC9801版で大丈夫ですか?」などと確認されたものだ。これ、慣れない人にとっては結構なハードルだったろうなあ、と思う。**買ってみたのに対応機種が違う**ので遊べないのだ。

I initially understood のに as "although" but I then realized that の might refer to the game that is brought and に belongs to 対応機種. So, 買ってみたのに対応機種が違う is understood as "compatible computer that can run the game they brought is different from what they have..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial interpretation is correct. This のに is simply "although".

As for why your second interpretation is incorrect, remember that ～に is an adverbial modifier that never modifies a noun like 対応機種. The noun phrase "compatible computer that can run the one they brought" is 買ってみたのに対応**する**機種 (対応 is now a verb). You can also say 買ってみたのの対応機種 (the second の is a noun-linking particle), although this one is a bit clumsy.